# Entity Framework best practices for multi threading and local storage

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

So I have a multithreaded application that uses a local database with sql ce 4.0. This app has no remote database. I tend to have a lot of issues with multiple threads accessing the database, despite my attempts to use locks a as well as saving errors. I haven't really seen too much on entity framework and local databases. I have currently on global dbcontext. Should I be using a new instance each time I need to use it in this case? How will that affect performance? Will it be anymore safer? I'm afraid data will get lazy loaded over and over when it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be using a new instance each time I need to use it in this case?

Yes.

> How will that affect performance?

Negligible.

> Will it be anymore safer?

No.

> I'm afraid data will get lazy loaded over and over when it doesn't need to be.

Once per context. Lazy loading occurs when you access a navigation property that isn't materialized yet. Use explicit loading if you want to prevent this.

Comment: For your last point. If say a thread creates a context then has to lazy load some data, process it, then cleans up and ends. then 10 seconds later the another thread creates a context and has to lazy load the same data it just did 10 seconds ago, couldn't that be avoided with the global context? What's your thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes, that's the case, and to prevent that you use explicit loading (`.Include()`).

Comment: Well I could persist a separate collection and only update the database to prevent that problem, but then I feel like I'd have to reinvent change tracking which is already there. Have you experimented with this?

Comment: Is performance currently a problem if you take the "one dbcontext per operation" approach? If not, I would advice against reinventing the wheel named caching. Especially cache invalidation is tricky to get right.

Comment: It could be if I the user has accumulated a lot of data they collected. I might have to do a where clause on 1000's or 10000's of rows of data for each transaction. That will probably trigger a lazy load on that table, which could add some overhead.